# Meaning of parameter "kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns" in RHEL6/RHEL7

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, scheduling

While studying the kernel behaviour from RHEL6 to RHEL7, we came across [an explanation on RHEL6 kernel parameters](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/177953):

> **> kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns**
>
> sched_min_granularity_ns is the initial value for the scheduler
>   period. The scheduler period is a period of time during which all
>   runnable tasks should be allowed to run at least once. While CFS has
>   no concept of time slices, you can think of the period as the initial
>   chunk of time which is then divided evenly into timeslices, one for
>   each runnable process. Note that this tunable only specifies the
>   initial value. When too many tasks become runnable the scheduler will
>   increase the period to avoid shortening run times too much.
>
> /usr/share/doc/kernel-doc-2.6.32/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt
>
> **>kernel.sched_latency_ns**
>
> It configures targeted preemption latency for CPU bound tasks.

The description regarding the `kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns` parameter confused us. Our understanding of the parameter is that it is the minimum amount of time for which each runnable task would run on the CPU (i.e. time-slice provided to each runnable task). For `kernel.sched_latency_ns`, it is the period during which all runnable task(s) would run at least once.

We derive our understanding from many other articles, such as [this one](https://www.systutorials.com/239998/sched_min_granularity_ns-sched_latency_ns-cfs-affect-timeslice-processes/) and [that one](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/tuning/html/book.sle.tuning/cha.tuning.taskscheduler.html). Some links might refer to a different kernel version, but the general description of the parameter shouldn't become reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed.  The RHEL6 doc is not consistent with the document it cites.  Ignore it.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.32/source/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt#L95

> Thus the CFS scheduler has no notion of "timeslices" in the
>   way the previous scheduler had, and has no heuristics whatsoever.  There is
>   only one central tunable (you have to switch on CONFIG_SCHED_DEBUG):
>
> ```
> /proc/sys/kernel/sched_min_granularity_ns
> ```
>
> which can be used to tune the scheduler from "desktop" (i.e., low latencies) to
>   "server" (i.e., good batching) workloads.  It defaults to a setting suitable
>   for desktop workloads.

The default value of this in the same version was 1ms, which makes sense as minimum for a timeslice (corresponding to old-style CONFIG_HZ=1000).

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.32/source/kernel/sched_fair.c#L40

1ms is several times too small for a plausible default for "a period of time during which all runnable tasks should be allowed to run at least once".

```
/*
 * Targeted preemption latency for CPU-bound tasks:
 * (default: 5ms * (1 + ilog(ncpus)), units: nanoseconds)
 *
 * NOTE: this latency value is not the same as the concept of
 * 'timeslice length' - timeslices in CFS are of variable length
 * and have no persistent notion like in traditional, time-slice
 * based scheduling concepts.
 *
 * (to see the precise effective timeslice length of your workload,
 *  run vmstat and monitor the context-switches (cs) field)
 */
unsigned int sysctl_sched_latency = 5000000ULL;

/*
 * Minimal preemption granularity for CPU-bound tasks:
 * (default: 1 msec * (1 + ilog(ncpus)), units: nanoseconds)
 */
unsigned int sysctl_sched_min_granularity = 1000000ULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

[The document that you linked to](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/177953) contains these definitions:

> - **kernel.sched_latency_ns**
>     sched_latency_ns is the initial value for the scheduler period. 
>     The scheduler period is a period of time
>     during which all runnable tasks should be allowed to run at least once. 
>     While CFS has no concept of time slices,
>     you can think of the period as the initial chunk of time
>     which is then divided evenly into timeslices, one for each runnable process. 
>     Note that this tunable only specifies the initial value. 
>     When too many tasks become runnable
>     the scheduler will use kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns instead.
>     /usr/share/doc/kernel-doc-2.6.32/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt
> - **kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns**
>     sched_min_granularity_ns specifies the target minimum scheduler period
>     in which a single task will run. 
>     This tunable is used only when running load is high. 
>     Unlike sched_latency_ns,
>     this tunable specifies the target period allocated for each task to run
>     rather than the time in which all tasks should be run once.

So the web page has already been fixed —
it says “Updated 2018-08-30T21:11:42+00:00”;
i.e., about four days ago; two weeks after you posted your question.

Comment: No I quoted it as is at the time of posting the question. As you observed, the content is updated now.

Comment: I apologize for jumping to conclusions; I have revised my answer to reflect your version of the timeline.